# Why does Facebook sharer see my old website

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a domain name and it had a wordpress cms in it, I re-created the website using another cms (not wordpress). When I try to share the articles or any page, it gives me in the FB sharer badge "page not found", but when clicking on the link .. it opens the page normally as expected.

I tried using [Facebook Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and it still gives me "Bad Response"[image]

When clicking on the button "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" in the debugger, it shows me the source of the wordpress page, although I changed the name servers and it is pointing to the correct host.

Any ideas?

Comment: _“I changed the name servers“_ – how long ago? _“and it is pointing to the correct host”_ - for both IPv4 and IPv6? Facebook gives preference to the latter, so make sure that the records for both point at the new server now, resp. check that you got no old records for IPv6 still pointing to the old server somewhere, should the new one not support IPv6.

Comment: You are right .. I had 2 "AAAA" records was pointing to the old host, removed them and the sharing works now. Thanks man

Comment: Cool, added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and it is pointing to the correct host

For both IPv4 and IPv6?

Facebook gives preference to the latter, so make sure that the records for both point at the new server now, resp. check that you got no old records for IPv6 still pointing to the old server somewhere, should the new one not support IPv6.